# https.get call within forEach in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I am doing several `https.get` calls in a async.waterfall block. In the last `function(callback)`, I have a `forEach` loop that iterates over the variable I received in the last call and makes `GET` calls accordingly.

My problem is that when i see in the UI, it does not retrieve all files every time. Sometimes it shows all files but sometimes only partial files. The profile page render happens before all the REST calls are finished and fileData is not fully populated. How can i fix this? Here is my code -

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        //I do a https.get call here and pass on 2 arguments to the next method
    },

    function (var1, var2, callback) {
        //I do a https.get call here and pass on 2 + 1 arguments to the next method
    },

    function (var1, var2, var3, callback) {
        //Here i do a https OPTIONS call to get all the available REST endpoints and pass those as var4
    },

    function (var1, var2, var3, var4, callback) {
        var fileData = [];

        var4.forEach(function(element){
            const url = host + var1 + element;

            https.get(url, function (n) {
                var output = '';
                n.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    output += chunk;
                });

                n.on('end', function () {
                    var fileJson = JSON.parse(output);
                    console.log("FileJSON data here :", fileJson);
                    if(fileJson) {
                        if (fileJson.owner == req.user.username) {
                            fileData.push(fileJson);
                        }
                    }
                });

                if(var4[var4.length - 1] == element){
                    n.on('end', function () {
                        res.render('viewProfile',{
                            title: 'View Profile',
                            fileData: JSON.stringify(fileData),
                            events: JSON.stringify(var2),
                            customerEvents: JSON.stringify(var3)
                        });
                    });
                    callback(null, 'done');
                }
            }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            });
        });
    }
], function(err, result){
    if(err) return next(err);
});
```

Comment: You have to use `async.each`

Comment: I believe not `each`, but `eachSeries` though, because result of one call is used in ahother.